# Forms Authentication - Accessing User Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I’m having some difficulty understanding how to access specific user data while using Forms Authentication.

I have already set up Forms Authentication for a User and an Admin.

When a User tries to log in, here is the code that runs:

```
    protected void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = TextBoxEmail.Text.Trim();
        string password = TextBoxPassword.Text.Trim();
        UserType userType = UserType.User; //temporary value
        string firstName = string.Empty;
        string lastName = string.Empty;
        bool success = DBAppLayer.AuthenticateLogIn(email, password, out userType, out firstName, out lastName);
        if (success == true)
        {
            Session.Add("email", email);
            Session.Add("firstname", firstName);
            Session.Add("lastname", lastName);

            switch (userType)
            {
                case DBDataLayer.UserType.User:
                    FormsAuthenticationUtil.SetAuthCookie(email, "User,", false);
                    Response.Redirect("~/User/UserDashboard.aspx", false);
                    break;
                case DBDataLayer.UserType.Admin:
                    FormsAuthenticationUtil.SetAuthCookie(email, "Admin", false);
                    Response.Redirect("~/AdminArea/AdminDashboard.aspx", false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
             labelError.Text = "Bad username/password.";
        }
    }
```

This successfully redirects a User to their dashboard. Now when the User is in /User/UserDashboard.aspx, I want to display the User’s profile information that is stored in the database, such as the User’s job and age.

The problem is, I’m not sure how to access this specific User’s data in UserDashboard.cs. Do I need to create an Authentication Ticket? If so, would I do this in the login page?

Any links or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This completely depends on your business layer. Does it require you to create an "authentication ticket"? Can you not just access the data in the database directly via the users username/ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your call to `FormsAuthenticationUtil.SetAuthCookie` passes in `email` as the user id when you create the authentication cookie.  In your user dashboard page, the `User.Identity.Name` field will give you back this same email address.  Use that value to call your database and get the user's profile.

You are also storing the email address in the `Session` so you could get it from there as well.